# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name 'com.example.shopapp_tut'

Tags: flutter

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.shopapp_tut'

Comment: I think you have a problem with the package name,

Comment: thanks have sorted it out

Comment: You are welcome :)